# Using socket.io lib with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, socket.io

I'm new to development in objective-c / swift:

I'm trying to connect to a socket.io server by using the api
(https://github.com/MegaBits/SIOSocket)

i've imported it via cocoapods and bridging header into my project.

the completion of xcode look like this:

```
 var io: SIOSocket = SIOSocket.socketWithHost
(hostURL: String!>, response: ((SIOSocket!) -> Void)!(SIOSocket!) -> Void)
```

I don't know what to fill in as "response" !

the original declaration is:

```
+ (void)socketWithHost:(NSString *)hostURL 
                        response:(void(^)(SIOSocket *socket))response;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the autocomplete code got a little messed up. That second parameter is a closure -- this should be the code you can use to create the socket (using a trailing closure):

```
SIOSocket.socketWithHost("http://example.com") { 
    (socket: SIOSocket!) -> Void in

    self.socket = socket
    // any other response handling here
}
```

Note - this is an asynchronous method, so you can't directly assign the result. You'll need to have a `socket` property in your class that gets set via this method.

Comment: my memory grows like hell
SIOSocket.socketWithHost("http://localhost:1337", response: { socket in
            self.socket = socket
            self.socket!.onConnect = {
                println("Connected")
           }
            self.socket!.onDisconnect = {
               println("Disconnected")
           }
            self.socket!.onError = { println($0) }
            self.socket!.onReconnect = { println($0)  }
        })